# Bad connection with 30 clients on a Ruckus R750 router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, 802.11

I have 30 Win 10/11 laptop gaming computers in the office. I put a [**Ruckus R750 (AX)**](https://www.commscope.com/product-type/enterprise-networking/wireless-access-points/indoor/r750/) in the office and provide the wireless connection for the computers.

When 30 computers start to visit a website like Google, about half of the computers have a very bad connection and can't visit Google and keep loading. About 15 minutes later, the computers with the bad connection start to come back to Google, while it would be very smooth to use a mobile phone to watch Youtube.

Later I tried to divide 3 groups of computers, 10 computers in each group. I use 3 **TP-LinkEAP245** APs to provide network for each group.The connection will be okay.

So I think WIFI protocol is the main reason for this.
How to solve the problem ? Ruckus 750 should be okay to provide internet connect for 30 computer browsing Google.

Comment: @Peregrino69 sorry should be TP-LinkEAP245 x 3

Answer (score 0):

The description of the
[RUCKUS R750](https://www.commscope.com/product-type/enterprise-networking/wireless-access-points/indoor/r750/)
says this:

> The RUCKUS R750 is our high-end dual-band, dual-concurrent Wi-Fi 6 AP that supports 8 spatial streams (4x4:4 in 5GHz, 4x4:4 in 2.4GHz). The R750, with OFDMA and MU-MIMO capabilities, efficiently manages up to 1024 client connections with increased capacity, improved coverage and performance in ultra-high dense environments.

The number of `4x4=16` seems to agree with your experience that about
half of the 30 connections fails.

I would advise putting half of your computers on 5GHz and the other half
on 2.4GHz, which might work better. The router should be able to support 30
connections, at least according to the commercial information.

Comment: But it said up to 1024 client connections. The max is only 16 for 2.4ghz , 16 for 5ghz . 
Also , I can’t  manually change the channel to 2.4/5 Ghz .

Comment: Perhaps this router is not the one you need, or perhaps you need two such routers.